# Mocked Object not returning expected value

Tags: java, mockito

I'm unit testing my dao. I create a list, I add an object to my list and I tell mockito when my method is called, to return my list with a single object. However, when I look at what's returned from my dao method, it's an empty list. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
@InjectMocks
private Dao dao;

@Mock
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemp;

@Test
public void testGetData() {
    List<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<>();
    MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
    myObj.setMethod("method val");
    list.add(myobj);

    Mockito.when(jdbcTemp.query(anyString(), Mockito.any(PreparedStatementSetter.class),
            Mockito.any(Dao.MyRowMapper.class))).thenReturn(list);

    List<MyObj> res = dao.getData(param1, param2); // this is empty, instead of having a value of 1

    Assertions.assertThat(res).isNotNull();
}
```

My Dao class:

```
public List<MyObj> getData(String arg1, String arg2) {
    List<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<MyObj>();

    try {

        list.addAll(jdbcTemp.query(query, new PreparedStatementSetter() {
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement pstmt) throws SQLException {
                pstmt.setString(PARAM_ONE, arg1);
                pstmt.setString(PARAM_TWO, arg2);
            }
        }, new MyRowMapper()));
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        
    }
    
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception? (try logging in the catch block)

Comment: No, I was just getting back an empty object, I realized, it's because I'm not using a qualifier, since I have multiple db connections, but now I do have another problem of my jdbc being null

Comment: how do you initialize your dao?

Comment: Using InjectMock, is that incorrect?

Comment: I got past this issue, but I have a different one now, should I modify my question or create a new one?

Comment: Create a new one. Also post the solution you found as a reply.

Comment: @Spider iirc you would need to call `MockitoAnnotations.initmocks(this)` respectively `MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this).close()` before each test.

Comment: I don't think that's necessary, because I'm using the SpringJunitRunner, instead of SpringRunner, so my mocks are initialized.

Comment: Just created it, can you guys please look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63728108/anystring-is-null-instead-of-empty-string

Answer (score 1):

I actually made a mistake in describing the problem.

I had two jdbcTemplates in my dao.

So the way I resolved it is to use a `@Qualifier("jdbcTemplate")` when creating a mock jdbctemplate