# anyString() is null instead of empty string

Tags: java, mockito

I'm trying to test my dao, however when I pass anyString(), in my dao it's coming out as a null string and as a result, it's not returning my mocked object that I want

```
@InjectMocks
private Dao dao;

@Mock
@Qualifier("jdbcTemp")
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemp;

@Test
public void testGetData() {
    List<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<>();
    MyObj myObj = new MyObj();
    myObj.setMethod("method val");
    list.add(myobj);

    Mockito.when(jdbcTemp.query(anyString(), Mockito.any(PreparedStatementSetter.class),
        Mockito.any(Dao.MyRowMapper.class))).thenReturn(list);

    List<MyObj> res = dao.getData(param1, param2); // this is empty, instead of having a value of 1

    Assertions.assertThat(res).isNotNull();
}
```

My Dao

```
@Autowired
private String query;

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemp;

public List<MyObj> getData(String arg1, String arg2) {
    List<MyObj> list = new ArrayList<MyObj>();

    try {
        // query below is null instead of empty string
        list.addAll(jdbcTemp.query(query, new PreparedStatementSetter() {
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement pstmt) throws SQLException {
                pstmt.setString(PARAM_ONE, arg1);
                pstmt.setString(PARAM_TWO, arg2);
            }
        }, new MyRowMapper()));
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    
}

return list;
```

}

Comment: Try using any instead of anyString matcher. Your query string is null because there is no mock for it.

Comment: Any doesn't work either, you can't mix mocks with matchers in the when though, right?

Comment: I hope you tried any() not any(String.class). anyString doesnot match nulls. any(String.class) too does not match nulls but any() method does.

Comment: Yes any(), not the latter. I'm going to try to just create an h2 table to try to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

So as you mentioned correctly `anyString()` does only match for non-null Strings. and as you pass `query` into your method you should verify, that your autowired `query` is not null.
As an alternative you could stick to `any()` or `nullable(String.class)` which matches for null. Since your test does not depend on the `query` value you can safely use this.

However as your code does not show how your Injection works it is not possible for us to investigate your problem further. If this is necessary for you please add the relevant code parts.